# Using a data captured in JavaScript onchange event on another event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to be using the **firmType** captured on **event 1** on **event 2**.
How to accomplish that?

**code**

**event 1**

```
  $("body").on("change","#so_customer", function(v){
        customerFirm = $(this).find(":selected").data("employer");
        $("#customer_employer").val(customerFirm);
        $("#historyLink").show();
        $("#historyLink").attr("href",GSVTOOL.AJAX.BASE +  

        $container = $("#hp_deposit_id");
        $container.select2('val', '');

        firmType = $(this).find('option:selected').data("firmtype");

    });
```

**event 2**

```
   $("body").on("change", "#installment_id", function(){
        $container = $("#hp_deposit_id");
        $container.select2('val', ''); 
        instId = $(this).val();
        alert(firmType);
        url = 'erp/sales-orders/ajax-initial-deposit';
        data = 'firmType='+firmType+'&instId='+instId;
        loadDepositPlan($container, url, data);
    });
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: Are your 2 events handlers on the same page ? If yes, can't you just use a common variable that you would modify into event1 then retrieve in event2 ?

Comment: Declare the variable as global so you will be able to use them in both event handlers.

Comment: You also need to make sure that the variable is set when event2 is triggered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickest solution would be to define the firmType variable outside the scope of your two event handler functions, like so:

```
var firmType;

$("body").on("change","#so_customer", function(v){
    // [Code to find firmType]

    firmType = $(this).find('option:selected').data("firmtype");

});

$("body").on("change", "#installment_id", function(){
    alert(firmType) // Will display value as set in handler 1
});
```

as Moolie states, the `var` keyword locks the scope of the variable to the current scope and any scopes within it. Thus by defining it outside your two handlers, and omitting `var` from your references to `firmType` inside your first handler, the variable's value is updated "globally" in the first handler and therefore available in the second.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a global variable, but it appears you are already doing that.

You can define a local variable by using the `var` keyword in a function. If you omit this keyword or define the variable outside a function, then the variable will have global scope (meaning it will be known everywhere in your javascript code). Any global variables are actually properties of the `window` object btw.

For example :

```
var myGlobalVar = "This is a global variable";  // var in global scope, so a global var
function myFunction() {
    var myLocalVar = "This is a local variable";  // var in function scope, so a local var
    myGlobalVar2 = "Another global variable";  // No var used, so a global var
}

alert(myGlobalVar);  // Will alert 'This is a global variable'
alert(myLocalVar);  // Will alert 'undefined', as myLocalVar is not defined in global scope
alert(myGlobalVar2); // Will alert 'Another global variable'
```